# What is the 'index' in TFLite interpreter.get_input_details referring to?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I'm working on doing some inference with Keras/TensorFlow models but the documenation seems a little sparse so I'm trying to learn and document as much as possible as I go and not just rely on copied code examples. Examples include this line:

`interpreter.get_input_details()`

Which returns a list containing a single dictionary with the following info:

`[{'name': 'conv2d_input', 'index': 8, 'shape': array([ 1, 28, 28,  1]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]`

`get_output_details` returns something very similar. Most of this is self-explanatory but I'm not clear what the index refers to. Examples I've found show that the number is needed by the set_tensor and get_tensor methods. All I've found so far is a comment somewhere saying that this refers to a tensor index which seems like a tautology to me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In TFLite interpreter, all tensors are put into a tensor list (see the `TfLiteTensor* tensors;` in [TfLiteContext](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api_internal.h#L434)), the index is the index of tensor in the tensor list.

Comment: Thank you for that. So this list is some member of the interpreter object, and the index is the index of the the input tensor in that list, which contains all other tensors as discrete members? Do you know if there's any particular rhyme or reason to the ordering? Seems odd that my input tensor is index 8 and the output is index 3.

Comment: Conceptually, yes, but actually the list in [_context](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h#L518) of the Interpreter. How tensors are arranged in the list is decided by the program created the model.